# Sharepoint CU Download mirror available?

Tags: cumulative-update, sharepoint-server

The "request hotifx via email" pages from Microsoft are again not working and I need to install several CUs on my virtual machines.

Are there any ftp sources available?

Kind regards

Comment: Which CU are you looking for?

Comment: I have SP1 installed, and I am looking for Build 6129 (if I remeber correctly) to import a site collection, which needs some custom development. 
So far, every CU I could a grip on after SP1 did tell me "the expected version was not found" and then aborted.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at Todd Klindts site:
http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224

"SharePoint 2010 Build Numbers"

The direct links are working for me :)

Comment: This site is in my bookmarks. The problem was, that in 9 out of 10 cases the hotifx request via email didnt work from my office. 
I downloaded every hotifx I could find from home and brought them in to get my machines working.